# How to extract values from an object and return it in an array of strings with specific requirements

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, data-structures

I'm trying to build a function that will extract the values from an object and creates an array of strings.

In the snippet below, you can see an example of what I did until now but that is not fully correct to my requirements.

Let's say I have data as in the example

```
const data = {
      age: {
        min: '17',
        max: '66'
      },
      gender: ['male', 'female'],
      rosacea: 'true',
      rosacea_papulo_pustulosa: 'true',
      severe_rosacea: 'true',
      nurse_contact: 'true',
    };
```

Right now I'm getting an array of strings for every single value in fact the result if you run it is

```
[
  "17",
  "66",
  "male",
  "female",
  "true",
  "true",
  "true",
  "true"
]
```

But what I need is the following array based if we have or not a nested object inside the data

```
[
  * This is the result of age min: '17' and max: '66'
  "17 - 66",
  * This is the result of gender male and female
  "male - female",
  * The rest is ok as no nested objects
  "true",
  "true",
  "true",
  "true"
]
```

The above result is what I'm searching

Another example as this below data

```
{disease":{"valid":["MDD","PTSD"],"invalid":["None"]}}

// result expected
[
 "MDD - PTSD",
 "None"
]
```

My issue at the moment is how to get into the expected results plus needs to be a `-` between the aggregated results.

We can also have a situation where data looks like this

```
{ageGroup: ["1","2","3", ..., "n"]}

// result expected
[
 "1 - 2 - 3 ... etc ..."
]
```

The snippets abut my first attempt

```js
const data = {
  age: {
    min: '17',
    max: '66'
  },
  gender: ['male', 'female'],
  rosacea: 'true',
  rosacea_papulo_pustulosa: 'true',
  severe_rosacea: 'true',
  nurse_contact: 'true',
};

const getValues = (data, values = []) => {
  if (typeof data !== 'object') {
    return [...values, data];
  }
  return Object.values(data).flatMap((v) => getValues(v, values));
};

console.log(getValues(data))
```

Update

The nested objects will never go more deeply as per following example

```
age: {
  group1: {
    min: '1',
    max: '6'
  }
  group2: {
    min: '7',
    max: '10'
  }    
  },
```

Expected result as

```
[
'1 - 6',
'7 - 10'
]
```

Comment: How are more deeply nested data structures (object/array) supposed to be handled?

Comment: The deeply the nested object are going is as like
 `{disease":{"valid":["MDD","PTSD"],"invalid":["None"]}}`
There is no more of that will be like the example 
age { min ... max} 
key: value
key: [someValues]
key: { nested: {valid: [xxx, yyy], notValid: [zzz, hhh]}}

Will be no more complex nesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP already came up with a recursive approach.

In order to achieve the OP's expected result(s), one has to implement the recursively operating function in a way that it will concatenate any array-type's item and any of an object-type's value, regardless of the (currently processed) data-structure's nesting level.

And for the not to be concatenated first level entries of the OP's `data` object one just needs to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the very object's [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) by said recursive function.

```js
function stringifyDataRecursively(data) {
  let result = '';

  if (data && (typeof data === 'object')) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {

      result = data
        .map(stringifyDataRecursively)
        .join(' - ');

    } else {

      result = Object
        .values(data)
        .map(stringifyDataRecursively)
        .join(' - ');
    }
  } else {

    result = data;
  }
  return result;
}

const sampleData = {
  age: {
    min: '17',
    max: '66'
  },
  gender: ['male', 'female'],
  rosacea: 'true',
  rosacea_papulo_pustulosa: 'true',
  severe_rosacea: 'true',
  nurse_contact: 'true',
};
console.log(
  'stringified `sampleData` ...',
  Object
    .values(sampleData)
    .map(stringifyDataRecursively)
);

const sampleData_2 = {
  disease: {
    valid: ['MDD', 'PTSD'],
    invalid: ['None'],
  },
};
console.log(
  'stringified `sampleData_2` ...',
  Object
    .values(sampleData_2)
    .map(stringifyDataRecursively)
);
console.log(
  'stringified `sampleData_2.disease` ...',
  Object
    .values(sampleData_2.disease)
    .map(stringifyDataRecursively)
);

const sampleData_3 = {
  group1: {
    min: '1',
    max: '6',
  },
  group2: {
    min: '7',
    max: '10',
  }, 
};
console.log(
  'stringified `sampleData_3` ...',
  Object
    .values(sampleData_3)
    .map(stringifyDataRecursively)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The result is no real as expected if I pass data as { disease: { valid: [ 'MDD', 'PTSD' ], invalid: [ 'None' ] } } I should see only ['MDD - PTSD', 'None'] but I receive different results. The function should result as explained above.
I tried on my local machine and I did get not the right result.
From this JSFiddle you see what result I'm getting
https://jsfiddle.net/kx2djnp7/

Comment: @Jakub ... 1/2 ... The results of e.g. `sampleData`, `sampleData_3` and `sampleData_2.disease` are all meeting the OP's requirements for they all feature more than just a single first level object entry. But the result of `sampleData_2` as well, which is a single and all concatenated array item, meets the OP's requirements for `sampleData_2` features just a single `disease` entry. That's the reason why I was asking the OP at first place ... _"How are more deeply nested data structures (object/array) supposed to be handled?"_ ...

Comment: @Jakub ... 2/2 ... coming up then with a two folded generic flattening approach where one needs to apply the recursive object flattening and value concatenating function as callback to the mapping of all of an object's (first level) values. Thus either the OP always assures a consistent data structure or does know at which object level `Object.values( { /* ... */ } ).map(stringifyDataRecursively)` has to be run at. There is no other way of solving the OP's problem.

Comment: @Jakub … are there any questions left?

Comment: The scope changed as to achieve the result I need was need it to do different changes I gonna accept by the way